# Should all tag-info "about" pages now just link to Stack Overflow Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation

### Context

- Tag info pages on Stack Overflow

### Example

Compare:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python

### Details

Now that Stack Overflow Documentation exists, it seems reasonable to conclude that the "about" page for each tagged language should at least include a link to Stack Overflow Documentation by default. In the extreme, each tagged language can now just link directly to SO-Docs and have little more than an introductory blurb.

Comment: Tag info pages are supposed to detail how to use a tag, not the dictionary definition of the word or description of the language. A link to the docs page would be fine; You can edit tag wikis the same as anyone else with your rep :).

Comment: Makes sense ... guess I just got a bit excited about Documentation roll-out. Tryin to promote it :-)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I disagree based on observation of existing tag info pages that do provide definitions of the tag subject matter. Good examples include [JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/json/info) and [JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info). These tag info pages provide a definition, summary, links to related content, and basic (i.e. Hello world) examples.

Comment: @gfullam I apologize, I was thinking of tag excerpts. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts, especially *Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag* and *Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag*.

Comment: Related proposal, which I would love to see implemented: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331843/can-we-have-a-link-to-documentation-topic-example-from-the-tag-wiki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No. They should *become* documentation pages.

Existing tag info pages already provide community edited definitions of the tag subject matter that are well-suited to become "Overview" topics in [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation).

Some examples include:

- [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)
- [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)
- [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)
- [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
- [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json)

These tag info pages provide a definition, summary, links to related content, and basic (i.e. Hello world) examples.

In fact, I have found that most "Overview" topic pages have similar, but lower quality, information in the "Remarks" section.

Contrast the above tag info pages with the Remarks in the respective Documentation tag "Overview" topic pages:

- [Adding CSS to a
  document](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/293/adding-css-to-a-document#t=201607221218111212834&a=remarks)
- [Introduction to
  HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/html/217/introduction-to-html#t=201607221213226673106&a=remarks)
- [Hello World (compile and run your first Java
  program)](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/84/hello-world-compile-and-run-your-first-java-program#t=201607221209481675477&a=remarks)
- [Saying Hello from
  JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/saying-hello-from-javascript#t=201607221206080586929&a=remarks)
- [Introduction to
  json](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/json/889/introduction-to-json#t=201607221210529176645) *(Note: Awkwardly, this page has very little valuable information in the "Remarks" section; instead presenting it as a prose-only "example" without any code.)*

Documentation is the ideal home for the kind of introductory information you'd find on the tag info pages in Q&A, yet it is painfully absent there.

***At the very least, the "Overview" link on each tag's Dashboard in Documentation should link to the respective tag info page in Q&A.***

Answer (score 0):

### Link them or, better, incorporate the one in the other somehow.

We just opened up the [Postscript documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/postscript/5616/introduction-to-postscript#t=201609010449427415287) and one of the first additions was the complete text of the Postscript [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postscript/info).

Now I'm totally in favor of spreading this information far and wide. Indeed, I've been [reposting the same material](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/4uqhTeNg-ro/discussion) in nntp:comp.lang.postscript in lieu of a regular FAQ posting.

The problem is duplication of effort. It's not DRY to maintain one list in 2 places.

OTOH, I think simply linking from one to the other is underkill.