# Can we have a link to documentation topic/example from the tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation-topics

I am thinking it would be easier to navigate if there is a link to documentation topic or example directly (if relevant) from the tag wiki page.

For example, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info should have a link in sidebar to its documentation dashboard.

Also, [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python). If you hover over this tag, you get links to 'info', 'top users', and 'frequent'. The documentation URL can be linked here too.

Comment: Because...not enough people are finding the Documentation?

Comment: We should also have the other way: Docs to tag wiki

Comment: Related (not duplicate at all): *[Tutorial-style List for Documentation?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331804)*